# Security of Javascript redirecting

Tags: javascript, php, redirect

I have a series of checks which determine whether the user is eligible to access a page and if they are denied access I currently alert them and redirect them using Javascript. I realised that one could very easy turn off Javascript and bypass being redirected, so I added a  statement which uses PHP to redirect them.

```
<script>
    window.alert("Access denied.");
    window.location.href='index.php';
</script>

<noscript>
    <?php header('Location: index.php'); ?>
</noscript>
```

Is this better or should I redirect a different way?

Thanks

Comment: Client side scripts should only be used to make the user experience better. Anything security related should be done out of the scope of the user on the server side. You can for sure redirect using js to display a modal or anything else, but you need to make always sure the actual protection of your resources is done on in the scope of the server.

Answer (score 1):

First: You would need to send the header from PHP before you output any content (because then the headers would already be sent).

So you should do something like this at the top of your script:

```
<?php
if ($user_is_eligible) {
    header('Location: index.php');
    die();
}
```

The `die();` part is important because it ensures that the script stops there and doesn't send any content that's probably not for the user to see.